# PyTorch Memory Allocation cat and del

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following function:

```py
from typing import OrderedDict
import torch

def flatten_dict(
        aligned_feat: OrderedDict[str, list[torch.Tensor]], 
    ):
    num_batches = len(list(aligned_feat.values())[0])
    flat_features = [None] * num_batches

    for k in list(aligned_feat.keys()):
        for b in range(num_batches):
            if flat_features[b] is None:
                flat_features[b] = aligned_feat[k][b]
            else:
                flat_features[b] = torch.cat((flat_features[b], aligned_feat[k][b]))
        # free up mem
        del aligned_feat[k]
        print(f"{k}: {torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()}")

    return flat_features

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = ['0', '1', '2', '3']
    d = OrderedDict()

    for k in keys:
        d[k] = [torch.rand((50, 256, 7, 7)).to("cuda") for _ in range(4)]

    print(str(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()))
    data = flatten_dict(d)
    print(str(torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()))
```

I get the following output:

```
41943040 
0: 41943040 
1: 54487040 
2: 56995840 
3: 59504640 
59504640
```

Can you help me understand the change in max memory allocation? Why is it not increasing at key 0? Why is it increasing after the first increase? And is there another way of "flattening" the dict, without increasing the max allocated memory (also not increasing it in the function itself)? Be aware, that I cannot stack the list[torch.Tensor] in the input, as they could have different shape[0] (I just now for certain, that shape[1:] are always [256, 7, 7] and I do not need the dictionary data format anymore after flattening).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory increase is coming from the concatenation. Concatenation requires creating a new tensor in memory to hold the output of the concatenation.

To visualize, I added more reporting to your code

```py
def flatten_dict(
        aligned_feat: OrderedDict[str, list[torch.Tensor]], 
    ):
    num_batches = len(list(aligned_feat.values())[0])
    flat_features = [None] * num_batches

    for k in list(aligned_feat.keys()):
        for b in range(num_batches):
            if flat_features[b] is None:
                report_val = 'no cat'
                flat_features[b] = aligned_feat[k][b]
            else:
                report_val = 'cat' 
                flat_features[b] = torch.cat((flat_features[b], aligned_feat[k][b]))
            print(f"{k}: {torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()}, {report_val}")
        del aligned_feat[k]

    return flat_features
```

This produces

```py
41943040
0: 41943040, no cat
0: 41943040, no cat
0: 41943040, no cat
0: 41943040, no cat
1: 46960640, cat
1: 49469440, cat
1: 51978240, cat
1: 54487040, cat
2: 54487040, cat
2: 54487040, cat
2: 54487040, cat
2: 56995840, cat
3: 56995840, cat
3: 56995840, cat
3: 56995840, cat
3: 59504640, cat
59504640
```

To your next question `is there another way of "flattening" the dict, without increasing the max allocated memory`, you would need to "flatten" the dict in a way that did not involve writing new tensors to memory. There's a lot of "it depends" based on your use case, but generally speaking if you want to merge tensors into a new tensor, that will require additional memory usage because the process of creating the new tensor requires both the input tensors and the output tensors to be held in memory simultaneously.

Also note that `torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated()` tracks the max memory allocation from the start of the process. It does not reset when memory is deleted. You can track ongoing memory use with `torch.cuda.memory_allocated()`.

Running your original code with `torch.cuda.memory_allocated()` shows the effect of deleting the original tensors

```py
41943040
0: 41943040
1: 41041920
2: 41943040
3: 41041920
41041920
```